# Reading a file from the filesystem

Tags: android

I am trying to read a file from /data partition in Android. I wrote a test App and then started it on the emulator. Then I used "adb push local_path_to_file /data/mydir/file1" to copy file1 under /data/mydir/.

Now I tried the following in my App and nothing happens :(

How to read a file saved in the /data? What is wrong with my code?

Here is the snippet code:

```
            try {

            File source = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/data/pu/file1");    
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(source);
            String fileStr = new String(ReadBytesOfFile(is).toString);
            System.out.println("file out ="+ fileStr);
            is.close(); 
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                Log.d("file","NOT FOUND");
            }


         public byte [] ReadBytesOfFile (InputStream input) throws IOException {
            long length = input.available();
            byte[] rbuffer = new byte[(int) length];
            input.read(rbuffer);
            return rbuffer;
         }
```

Comment: I also tried just: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/data/pu/file1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot store files in `/data` in production, except in the location returned to you by `getFilesDir()`, so you really need to rethink your approach.

Second, you are not trying to read from `/data`. Your code reads from a `/data` directory *inside of* `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. The precise location of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` varies by device and OS version, but `/mnt/sdcard` is the most common spot. Hence, you are presently trying to read from something like `/mnt/sdcard/data`, not `/data`.

[Here is the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) on data storage in Android.

Comment: Thanks CommonWare. Just another question, sdcard dir seems to be mounted as READ ONLY. So how do I push/copy my files to this partition and then read from them? I actualy thought I was reading from the sdcard!

Comment: @user489152: Your emulator probably does not have an emulated SD card. You need to define one using the AVD Manager. And if you do not know what "inside" means with respect to a directory, there is little I can do to help you.

Comment: Oops well, deleting that comment. I wanted to know if it was the directory for private data of Apps not visible to other Apps. Anyway got it now.

Comment: @user489152: `getFilesDir()` is the directory for private data.